# DRBD status :- UpToDate/Diskless

Tags: drbd

I was configuring two DRBD shares for our servers. I have successfully completed two DRBD share creation, but while checking the status one of the shares status is showing as "UpToDate/Diskless".

drbd-overview command output

```
[root@server1~]#drbd-overview 

  1:drbd   Connected Secondary/Primary UpToDate/UpToDate C r---- 
  2:drbd1  Connected Primary/Secondary   UpToDate/Diskless C r----

[root@server2~]#drbd-overview

  1:drbd   Connected Primary/Secondary UpToDate/UpToDate C r---- 
  2:drbd1  Connected Secondary/Primary   Diskless/UpToDate C r----
```

The DRBD is working correctly and i can mount the devices on primary nodes.

But i am wondering about one DRBD share status. is that status is normal or is there anything wrong with that share ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This is not normal at all (everything else than `UpToDate` is not normal). Check if the disk you configured in the config file exists and works correctly.

[From the docs](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/ch-admin.html):

> Diskless. No local block device has been assigned to the DRBD driver.
>   This may mean that the resource has never attached to its backing
>   device, that it has been manually detached using drbdadm detach, or
>   that it automatically detached after a lower-level I/O error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have re-created the DRBD share and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

these commands will help you fix the problem.
Run the following commands on the Diskless node.

drbdadm detach 
drbdadm connect 
drbdadm attach 
restart the drbd service <--- this is important step

Answer (score 0):

Both nodes should be UpToDate

Look like you should attach the disk at the diskless side. Go to the secondary node and execute

`drbdadm attach drbd1`